# return value of sqlite3_get_table when the value we are searching is not there

Tags: c, sqlite

For sqlite3_get_table.

Lets say the file is exists,
the Table inside it also exist.
but the cell we are searching is not exists.

i need to know what will be returned when it could not find what it is searching for.

what will be return value? is it NULL? or is it 0?

I am searching for my data. but if that cell contains any value/string, it will return the value/string when we select it. but in case we are searching in entire file, we couldnt get the specific value/string that we wanted. so is it returning NULL or 0 or is it just empty? If it is empty, what am i supposed to do for checking condition?

lets say for checking part right now, i do this to check is it grabbing any values/string from the file or not, before i check what it is getting, is it really the data that i wanted.

if(&TableStudentName[i][j] == NULL)           //if the string exists

and

if(&TableStudentName[i][j] != NULL)           //if the string not exists

I am asking this since for when the string is not exists, sometimes my code is working just fine & sometimes its stuck there.

Comment: by cell you mean column or your data?

Comment: @Mansoor i edited the question above for better view of my question.

Comment: Why are you using that function? The very first line of it's [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/free_table.html) is *This is a legacy interface that is preserved for backwards compatibility. Use of this interface is not recommended.*

Comment: I am using this function since the code that was developed by the previous dev is using this. and if i were to change it, a lot of file will be effected, so we are trying to not changing those as it will cause a lot of changes and errors to be fixed.